# Slick carousel after slide change run typewriter function

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I am using [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and am trying to get a typewriter effect to run after the slide changes. See slick [documentation](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

The typewriter function source I am using is from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_typewriter).

```
<div class="slick-rick">
  <div class="phrase" data-phrase="Wubba lubba dub dub!">1</div>
  <div class="phrase" data-phrase="Eek barba durkle">2</div>
  <div class="phrase" data-phrase="And that's the wayyyyyy the news goes!">3</div>
  <div class="phrase" data-phrase="Uh ohhhh! Somersoult jump!">4</div>
  <div class="phrase" data-phrase="Hit the sack, Jack!">5</div>
  <div class="phrase" data-phrase="GRASSSSS... tastes bad!">4</div>
</div>
```

My script...

```
$('.slick-rick').slick({
  arrows: false

}).on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

  // empty's html from all slides
  $('.slick-slide .phrase', this).empty();

  // counter
  var i = 0;

  // the text pulled from slide data attribute
  var txt = $('.slick-current .phrase', this).data('phrase');

  // typing speed
  var speed = 50;

  console.log(txt);

    // the function to type the data phrase out
  function typeWriter() {

    if (i < txt.length) {
      $('.slick-current .phrase', this).innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
      i++;
      setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
    }
  }

  // run the function
  typeWriter();

});
```

See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/u8cjr4fy/

---

I have a few problems...

1. The typewriter function does not work and I'm not sure why?
2. I want to run the function on `.slick-rick` initialisation, but slicks `.on('init',` event, does not fire on `init`?
3. It would of been nice to use slick events to target the slide, but the `currentSlide` returns the slide interger and I cant see an obvious way of using this to target the current slide, because the returned interger does not match slicks `data-slick-index`

Any help would be awesome thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is

> The Element property innerHTML gets or sets the HTML or XML markup contained within the element.

You cannot apply that to a jQuery object:

```
$('.slick-current .phrase', this).innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
```

Change that line, using [.html(function)](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function), to:

```
$('.slick-current .phrase').html(function(idx, html) {
    return html + txt.charAt(i)
});
```

```js
$('.slick-rick').slick({
    arrows: false

}).on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

    // empty's html from all slides
    $('.slick-slide .phrase', this).empty();

    // counter
    var i = 0;

    // the text pulled from slide data attribute
    var txt = $('.slick-current .phrase', this).data('phrase');

    // typing speed
    var speed = 50;

    console.log(txt);

    // the function to type the data phase out
    function typeWriter() {

        if (i < txt.length) {
            $('.slick-current .phrase').html(function(idx, html) {
                return html + txt.charAt(i)
            });
            i++;
            setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
        }
    }

    // run the function
    typeWriter();

});
```

```css
.slick-rick .phrase {
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slick-rick">
    <div class="phrase" data-phrase="Wubba lubba dub dub!">1</div>
    <div class="phrase" data-phrase="Rikitikitavi, bitch!">2</div>
    <div class="phrase" data-phrase="And that's the wayyyyyy the news goes!">3</div>
    <div class="phrase" data-phrase="Uh ohhhh! Somersoult jump!">4</div>
    <div class="phrase" data-phrase="Hit the sack, Jack!">5</div>
    <div class="phrase" data-phrase="GRASSSSS... tastes bad!">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing the issue out. Really helped me a lot. Nice one man!